# How to install video drivers in LTSP chroot?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, fglrx, chroot, ltsp

We have an HP t520 thin client with AMD G-Series/Radeon R2E embedded graphics.

The AMD proprietary video driver solves a problem that the Ubuntu open-source video driver has with display detection.

So far I have been unable to install the fglrx-updates driver in the LTSP chroot, despite trying all of the following:

1. Entering `ltsp-chroot -p` on the server and running `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` then running `sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial`(amdconfig returns ‘No supported adapters detected’)
2. Install Ubuntu directly on thin client, install AMD video driver, install and build LTSP, then copy chroot to server and rebuild image (thin client won't boot from that image–despite running ltsp-update-image and ltsp-update-kernels after copying)
3. Boot thin client with open-source graphics, enter ‘ltsp-localapps xterm’ in terminal (the resulting xterm session will not auth sudo needed to install driver)

Server is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

In order to get root access you'll need to chroot into the directory (on the server) where the thin client filesystem is and run passwd. Once you've set a password you'll be able to log in to the root account. This may lead you to a solution.